# Unexpected '<' getting issue in magento 2 shipping information

Tags: magento2

```
Url: XXXXXXXXXXX/rest/V1/carts/16/shipping-information 
    {
 "addressInformation": {
     "billingAddress": {
        "city": "noida",
        "company": "iprag",
        "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Kumar",
        "postcode": "335001",
        "region": "UP",
        "street": ["D-84"],
        "telephone": "9413433217"
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
        "city": "noida",
        "company": "iprag",
        "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Kumar",
        "postcode": "335001",
        "region": "UP",
        "street": ["D-84"],
        "telephone": "9413433217"
      },
       "shippingCarrierCode": "flatrate",
      "shippingMethodCode": "flatrate"
    }
}
```

Hi developing react-native sample application .
I am adding to cart items after! i don't  know how to call address and how to place the order . Please give me anyone brief explain.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when your url is not what working, either your server is down or you jave not deployed your backend properly on the server. Hence, it is unable to get the proper response.

Comment: Hi Url working fine and server also working fine but still getting issue